# How can I install the Atheros AR8161 drivers without an internet connection?

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers

How can I install the Atheros AR8161 drivers without an internet connection for fedora19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `fresh` install of Fedora 19: 
Step 1: From a computer having access to internet, download the following packages from  [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org)

```
cpp-4.8.1-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
gcc-4.8.1-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
gcc-c++-4.8.1-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
glibc-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64.rpm
glibc-common-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64.rpm
glibc-devel-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64.rpm
glibc-headers-2.17-14.fc19.x86_64.rpm
kernel-devel-3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64.rpm
kernel-headers-3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64.rpm
libmpc-1.0.1-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
libstdc++-devel-4.8.1-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-5.16.3-264.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-Carp-1.26-243.fc19.noarch.rpm
perl-Encode-2.51-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-Filter-1.49-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-libs-5.16.3-264.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-macros-5.16.3-264.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-PathTools-3.40-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-264.fc19.noarch.rpm
perl-Pod-Simple-3.20-264.fc19.noarch.rpm
perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-246.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-Socket-2.009-2.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-threads-1.87-1.fc19.x86_64.rpm
perl-threads-shared-1.43-2.fc19.x86_64.rpm
```

Step 2: Copy them to the machine and run the command:

```
# yum install *.rpm
```

Step 3: Download [compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2%22%5dcompat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2) then run the commands:

```
# tar -xf compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2
# cd compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u
# ./scripts/driver-select alx && make && make install
# reboot
```

Taken From: http://commandlinewani.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-install-atheros-wired-lan.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the following packages on your system: Kernel headers, kernel development files and gcc compiler:

```
rpm -qa | grep 'kernel-headers\|kernel-devel\|gcc'
```

After that, download the alx driver from here:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2
```

Extract it, and compile it

```
tar -xjf compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2
cd compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
```

(now, as root)

```
make install
modprobe alx
```

There is a feature request to include alx on Fedora kernel. Meanwhile, you will have to download manually your RPM's from internet if you don't have any other way to connect

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=842367